# Adding Attributes to Global Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, scope

Let's say that I have a block of code like this:

```
keysPressed = new Object();
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    keysPressed[e.charCode] = true;
}
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    keysPressed[e.charCode] = false;
}
```

This should theoretically leave me with an object where I can go `keysPressed.w` to check if 'w' is currently pressed.

I can see in my JavaScript console that all of the attributes are defined like normal, but whenever I try to access them, it says that they're undefined. I suspect that the attributes have a local scope inside the functions where they're defined, and can't be accessed elsewhere. Is there any way to solve this problem without creating a whole bunch of global variables?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `charCode` returns a numeric value.  So instead of adding a property for `w` it's adding an property for the number `87`.  You want to use `String.fromCharCode` to get the string representation here

```
keysPressed = new Object();
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    keysPressed[String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)] = true;
}
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    keysPressed[String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)] = false;
}
```

Now code like the following will work (note the use of upper case W instead of lower)

```
if (keysPressed.W) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly the answer I was looking for.